# AngularJs - Input text box is not populated by the initial value id

Tags: html, angularjs

I really hope you can help me with this. I am having trouble showing the ID population the textbox when I modify the form.
Let me explain it to you in detail

This is my list:

```
myList = [{ 'id':100, 'name': 'test mission 1' },
    { 'id':102, 'name': 'test mission 2' },
    { 'id':103, 'name': 'test mission 3' },
    { 'id':104, 'name': 'test mission 4' },]
```

This is my HTML with a workable typeahead function.

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="selected"
       typeahead="mission as mission.name for mission in myList | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8"
       name="mission_name"
       disabled>

<input type="hidden"
       name="mission_id"
       ng-model="selected"
       value="{{field.value}}">
```

so whatever name value you type from the textbox naming `mission_name`, the id of that name will automatically populate the textbox naming `mission_id`. This is already workable and this is not the real problem. Because the only value that I want to save to the database is the `mission_id`. Let me show you my controller first.

This is my controller

```
angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('TypeaheadCtrl_{{ field.id_for_label }}', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = "{{ mission.name }}";
    $scope.myList = {{ Mission|safe }};
});
```

The problem is, when I want to modify this data and i go to the form, I can only see that mission_name is populated by the data, it must be because i put an initial value such as `$scope.selected = "{{ mission.name }}"`. However in `mission_id` textbox, the initial value is also the same as the value of `mission_name` maybe bacause of `ng-model`. What I want to do is to see the `mission_id` value and not the `mission_name` value.

I hope my explanation is clear. I really need help to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning this

```
       <input type="hidden"
   name="mission_id"
   ng-model="selected"
   value="{{field.value}}">
```

to

```
       <input type="hidden"
         name="mission_id"
           ng-model="selected1"
         value="{{field.value}}">
```

Then in js

```
     $scope.selected = "{{ mission.name }}";
     $scope.selected1 = "{{ mission.id }}";
     $scope.myList = {{ Mission|safe }};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also did this and when I use a different ng-model in mission_id field it is still not working.

Comment: Just try changing this mission as mission.id for mission in myList in typehead  just for try

Comment: if I change it into mission.id, the list that will be showing is the ID's wherein I want to show the list of the name, so whenever I select a name, it's ID will automatically populate the other textbox

Comment: Then it seems one solution ng-model="selected.id" instead of selected in second and remove $scope.selected = "{{ mission.name }}";

Comment: Do you think this is fine? `$scope.selected = [
  {id:'{{mission.id}}',name:'{{mission.name}}'}
    ];`

Comment: what do you want to do with this?

Comment: I am thinking of something like ng-model='selected.name' and the other one  has to be ng-model='selected.id'. I am not pretty sure if this syntax is correct or not